# Calculation is wrong, Rounding wrong

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding, formula, precision

For some reasons Excel doesn't calculate correctly:

Calculation = 4642,83 * (60,13-60,08) / 66,84 = 3,47...

Excel = 3,40.

It is really important that I calculate directly because it will be rounded. The first one is rounded to 4, the second one is rounded to 3 which is a big difference in my calculation.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

EDIT: Calculation in my excel sheet

```
   =ABS(K2*(K11-K10)/K13) ==> gives me 3,40

    K2 = 4642,83
    K11 = 60,08
    K10 = 60,13
    K13 = 66,84
```

Other sheet:

```
 =ABS(A1*(A2-A3)/A4) ==> gives me 3,47

A1 = 4642,83
A2 = 60,13
A3 = 60,08
A4 = 66,84
```

Comment: Without a complete review of your code, anything said is only a wild guess and not allowed on SO: [mcve]

Comment: Excel actually calculates 3.47309245960532. You need to show us exactly what you are doing because obviously you are doing something wrong.

Comment: What version of excel do you have that rounds **3.47** to **4**?

Comment: Added pictures.

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Hire someone to do this for you. You cannot even post an image that correctly identifies the problem.

Comment: I dont know what the problem is so i cant identify it with an image. I entered the numbers in a new excel sheet and then it does it correctly to 3,47. But in my excel sheet it gives 3,40.

Comment: You could have included row and column references as well as the formula (in the formula bar) so that we could have told you where your problem was. I'm assuming that you are using cell references and not hard numbers in your calculation. In any event **DO NOT POST IMAGES!!!**

Comment: Okey, i will not post images anymore. I am indeed using cell references. What information do i need to provide?

Comment: OK, Go to Home, Number and click the little `←0.00` button a few times. I changed your values while still displaying what you see (averaged by cell number format) and came up with **3.16**.

Comment: @user2737015, the problem can lie in the formatting. What you see as a result in the cell is disguised behind formatting. The value itself can be different. E.g. **60,08** could be 60,0849999999; **60,13** could be 60,125; etc. The results then vary from what you expect.

Comment: Like @BranislavKollár SAID.

Comment: I tried the formatting thing but it still displays 3,40120302 but on another sheet it displays 3,47309246. it are the exact same numbers and same formatting...

Comment: Duplicate of [Round to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085582/round-to-two-decimal-places/29086405#29086405)

Comment: Found the problem. In cell K10 the actual number was 60,13...... which made the solution display 3,40 i used the round function in excel to round it to 2 decimals. Now it displays 3,47 => 3,5 => 3 used the round up function to round it to 4.

Answer (score 0):

1- Check out `Format Cells` for result Cell.

the category should be `General` or `Number` with appropriated `Decimal Places`.

2- Make sure the above formula is:

```
=4643.83*(60.13-60.08)/66.84
```

It returns: 3.473840515

If you set about two, the true result is returns.

Thanks for edition details, thus the precision is in this matter, is related two above.

Pic1: Calculating your original question expression.

[image: Please take a look at this image]

And bellow one as your above question edition:

[image: And this as your above edition]

Comment: "Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Help people as much as you can, but never tell them what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the numbers are being calculated to a higher precision. Try,

```
=ABS(ROUND(K2, 2)*(ROUND(K11, 2)-ROUND(K10, 2))/ROUND(K13, 2))
```

Look into the 'Precision as displayed' option but be sure to understand all of the caveats before deciding to do it.

[image]